# Make python module as an installable API

Tags: command-line, apt, yum, python

I am developing an API in Unix environment for virtual machines. Most of the modules are developed in python. I have few questions on this.

I want to make this as an installable API, I mean to install through apt-get/ yum install. In terms of yum I have to create a repository and place the module in a FTP location. But I didn't get the complete picture about that.  What are the steps I need to do to achieve this or some reference URL's would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should approach this as a two step process.

First make your api installable using [`pip`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/) by creating a `setup.py` file for the project and use [setuptools](http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/). There is quite a lot to go through and I recommend you follow some of the examples out there to go through the steps before you start tweaking to get your own project installable this way. Extension in e.g. C that need compilation can be included.¹

Once that works correctly, you can use [`stdeb`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/stdeb#sdist-dsc-distutils-command) to base a Debian installable package from that (`.deb`).
The facilities for building an `rpm` [are built-in](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/builtdist.html#creating-rpm-packages), but require the `rpm` utility to be available.²

¹ <sub>If you get confused about setuptools, distutils, distribute, etc., welcome to the club. Read [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14753678/1307905) for some comparison and history, and put [this under your pillow](https://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html)</sub>
² <sub>It takes some care to get this to work, it is possible to have a working setup.py that doesn't work (well) as `.rpm` or `.deb`. Start with the working examples and go from there</sub>

Comment: My CLI(Command Line Interface) includes one or two java and c files but others are python files. This CLI is for virtual machine placement which is similar to Amazon EC2. So shall I make it as python package? I read in the PyPi portal that packages for python language only has to be uploaded. Could you suggest me on this?

Comment: You can upload the python packages to PyPI, but if they are not of general use, you could also setup private repository using [devpi](http://doc.devpi.net/latest/) and upload your own python packages there. That also speeds up download from PyPI as it caches files from there.

Comment: Thank you. And here is my [setup.py](https://github.com/dcsolvere/virtdc/blob/master/setup.py) file. I want to install the entire virtdc project under /var/lib folder. My drone.io build is failing for this setup.py file. Could you comment on this. That would be very helpful.